# Why a ListView in a Fragment cannot work?

Tags: android, listview, fragment

> Why there's an error in [logcat : open this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDRF4.png)

This java i copied from extend ListActivity

I change ListActivity to Fragment and the wrong code, i add getActivity() but ListView lv = getListView(); is wrong

can you help me?

```
public class menuTIFragment extends Fragment {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
protected ListView lv;
// buat json object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> classList;

// url untuk get semua buku tamu
private static String url_Class = Koneksi.DISPLAY_MATKULTI;

// JSON Node
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_JUMLAH ="jumlah";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id_matkul";
private static final String TAG_NAMA = "nama_matkul";


// pendaftaran JSONArray
JSONArray jumlah = null;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.
            menu,container,false);

    classList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadClass().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();
    ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String id_matkul = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idmatkul2)).getText().toString();

            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), TabFragment.class);

            in.putExtra(TAG_ID, id_matkul);
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // jika kode hasil sama dengan 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // maka diterima
        // ketika user ngedit atau menghapus data
        // reload screen
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        getActivity().finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

class LoadClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(menuTIFragment.this.getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    /**
     * dapetkan semua produk dari get url di background
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Buat Parameter
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // ambil json dari url
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_Class, "GET", params);

        // cek logcat untuk response dari json
        Log.d("Semua Hasil: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // cek jika tag success
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // data ditemukan
                // ambil array dari bukutamu
                jumlah = json.getJSONArray(TAG_JUMLAH);

                // tampilkan perulangan semua produk
                for (int i = 0; i < jumlah.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jumlah.getJSONObject(i);

                    // simpan pada variabel
                    String id_matkul = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String nama_matkul = c.getString(TAG_NAMA);



                    // buat new hashmap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // key => value
                    map.put(TAG_NAMA, nama_matkul);
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id_matkul);




                    // masukan HashList ke ArrayList
                    classList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // jika tidak ada data
                // maka jalankan tambahkan buku tamu
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        HomeFragment.class);
                // tutup semua proses sebelumnya
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * jika pekerjaan di belakang layar selesai maka hentikan progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // hentikan progress ketika semua data didapat
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // perbarui screen
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        menuTIFragment.this.getActivity(), classList,
                        R.layout.menu2, new String[]{TAG_NAMA, TAG_ID},
                        new int[]{R.id.matkul2, R.id.idmatkul2});
                // perbarui list pendaftaran
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}}
```

Comment: `I change ListActivity to Fragment` **WRONG**: Change to `ListFragment`, instead.

Comment: Which is line no 173 in `menuTI Fragment` ?